# Quiero cambiar el color de un texto dentro de un script ya definido

Tags: javascript, html, css

No soy bueno en html así que mi pregunta puede resultar muy simple pero para mí no lo es. Tengo un código de script para insertar en una web, pero no sé como darle formato al texto, darle color (azul) u otra tipografía (itálica por ejemplo) que no sea la que me pone automaticamente la web. Les paso el script para ver si alguien me facilita la solución. Gracias.

```
<div id="changeText" ></div> 
<script type="text/javascript">    
   var counter = 0;
   var elem = document.getElementById("changeText");
   setInterval(change, 5000);
   function change() {
     elem.innerHTML = text[counter];
     counter++;
     if(counter >= text.length) { counter = 0; }
   }
</script>
```

Comment: Aplicales estilos por medio de CSS

Comment: No sé como hacerlo

Comment: @RafaelAcosta, claramente el código es JS no veo por que regresar la etiqueta Java

Comment: @Aprendiz La verdad es que no se como se cambió, parece que fui yo.. lo modifico. Gracias.

Answer (score 1):

Lo que puedes hacer es obtener el elemento al que quieres cambiarle los estilos,

```
document.getElementById("changeText")
```

agrega el objeto style y seguido cualquiera de sus propiedades en este caso el color y su valor rojo

```
document.getElementById("changeText").style.color="red";
```

lo mismo para cualquier estilo que quieras agregar, aqui dejo tu codigo:

```
    <div id="changeText" ></div> 
<script type="text/javascript">    
   let texto = document.getElementById("changeText");
   texto.style.color="red";
   texto.style.font="italic bold 20px arial,serif";

   var text = ["Dato","Dato2","Dato3"]
   var counter = 0;
   var elem = document.getElementById("changeText");
   setInterval(change, 5000);
   function change() {
     elem.innerHTML = text[counter];
     counter++;
     if(counter >= text.length) { counter = 0; }
   }
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

El cambio de tipografía lo puedes hacer con la etiqueta
`<i> </i>`

El cambio de color lo puedes hacer usando el atributo `style`, que te permite insertar `css` o estilos a la misma etiqueta, con esto el atributo `color` te permitirá establecer un color para el texto. El valor del color puede ser el nombre de un color, un valor Hexadecimal o RGB, una lista de nombres válidos para el color la encuentra [aquí](http://www.colors.commutercreative.com/grid/).

Con esto tu código podría quedar de la siguiente forma

```html
    <div id="changeText"></div> 
    <script type="text/javascript">

    var text = ["Uno", "Dos", "Tres", "Cuatro"];

        var counter = 0;
        var elem = document.getElementById("changeText");
        setInterval(change, 5000);
        function change() {
        elem.innerHTML = `<i style="color: blue">${text[counter]}</i>`;
            counter++;
            if(counter >= text.length) { counter = 0; }
        }
    </script>
```

Comment: Dado que el OP va iniciando con CSS, creo que lo mas correcto sería enseñarle como aplicar CSS desde las etiquetas style accediendo por medio de sus id o clases

Comment: @Aprendiz En el caso que quiera utilizar múltiples colores según el contenido, el camino más fácil de hacer esto es mediante Javascript ya que setear una clase para un color específico puede ser más engorroso. Hace falta más contexto para saber qué estrategia le servirá más.

Comment: Muchas gracias, funcionó perfecto.